# How to use ScriptReference Component for my ContextHub Segment?

Tags: javascript, aem

I want to use Script Reference Component for my **ContextHub** Segment. I have created a JavaScript file named "**scriptTest.js**" under **/apps/script/**. I have provided path in the **Script Name** field. It shows **User script "scriptTest.js" not found**. 
Where can I put my JavaScript file so that contextHub segment is able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

use contexthub.segment-engine.scripts as Category of your clientlib.

and register your script i.e.

```
ContextHub.SegmentEngine.ScriptManager.register('new-test-script', testScript);
```